# Duplicate request when opening a target="_blank" link in a standalone Chrome PWA

Tags: google-chrome, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I have a website which runs a service-worker. When I install the website as a PWA App using Add to Homescreen (standalone mode), the site works fine, except that any `target="_blank"` links *cause a duplicate request on the server side* - there are two simultanous requests, but only one window opens. This happens even when service worker has no caching logic (fetch handler is empty)

- I'm seeing this on Chrome (Huawei, Android 9), as well as Chrome (Samsung, Android 6) and Samsung Internet Browser - but not on iOS Safari.
- The duplicate request happens no matter if there is any fetch event implemented in PWA or not
- Only one debugger event gets caught in service-worker fetch event, fiddler sees two requests
- Only happens in "installed" PWA, not in regular browser or non-PWA homescreen website shortcut
- The resource is not cached (or supposed to be cached)

I've made a minimal repro application that I can replicate the issue in:

```
/index.html
/page.html
/service-worker.js
/manifest.json
```

index.html:

```html
<head><link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json"></head>
<body>
    <a href="/page.html" target="_blank">CLICK ME</a>
    <script>navigator.serviceWorker.register('/service-worker.js', { scope: '/' });</script>
</body>
```

manifest.json:

```
{
    "background_color": "#FFFFFF",
    "description": "Repro application",
    "display": "standalone",
    "name": "Repro application",
    "short_name": "Repro application",
    "start_url": "/index.html",
    "theme_color": "#FFFFFF"
}
```

service-worker.js:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    self.addEventListener('fetch', function (event) { });
    self.addEventListener('activate', function (event) { });
}());
```

Also happens without fetch event at all, or with fetch event just returning a network fetch promise (so default browser behaviour)

page.html content doesn't matter (if it's not there, it just 404's twice)

Only the target="_blank" links hit the server twice, "_self" works fine. Any ideas how to track down what's causing the extra hit?